# How to get the multiple data objects from ajax to my controller in spring mvc

Tags: javascript, java, json, ajax, spring-mvc

Here the first ajax is hitting my controller sucessfully by hitting url *'getMergeRuleMaxCount'* but when i try to hit this url *'getMergingDatasets'*
so that my control reaches to controller and i can get the *data* send by ajax in controller, first of all i am not able to get into controller and it is giving me some exception which is mentioned below.
As per my understanding issues is coming while sending the multiple data to my controller.

> Iam not getting what iam doing wrong, and how should i get the data in my controller?

Can any body let me know the posible solution?

**Exception**

```
WARN : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Required request body is missing: public com.hcl.ae.model.MergeRule com.hcl.ae.controller.MergeRuleController.getMergingDatasets(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,com.hcl.ae.model.MergeRule) throws java.io.IOException
```

**Merge.js**

```
function mergingDataSetValidation(){
            var company = $("#company").val();
            if (company=="") {
                alert("Please select company");
            }
            var companyClass = $("#companyClass").val();
            var companyName = jQuery("#company").find("option[value='" + jQuery("#company").val() + "']").text();
            var className = jQuery("#companyClass").find("option[value='" + jQuery("#companyClass").val() + "']").text();
            $
                    .ajax({
                        type : "GET",
                        url : "getMergeRuleMaxCount",
                        success : function(data) {
                            var count = data;
                            var  selectedValue = "Merge_" + companyName + "_" + className + "_Rule_" + count;
                            $("#mergeRuleName").val(selectedValue);

                                    var parameter = {
                                            "companyId": company,
                                            "classId" : companyClass 
                                        };

                                    $
                                    .ajax({
                                        type : "GET",
                                        url : "getMergingDatasets",
                                        dataType: "json",
                                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                                        data : JSON.stringify(parameter),
                                        /*data : 'company=' + company  + '&class=' + companyClass,*/
                                        success : function(data) {
                                            alert("success");
                                            return;
                                        },
                                        error: function(error) {
                                            alert("Error occured while fetching merging datasets..!!")
                                        }   
                                    });

                        },
                        error: function(error) {
                            alert("Something went wrong..!!, please refresh the page and try again.")
                        }
                    });
        };
```

**Controller**

```
    @JsonView(Views.Public.class)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/getMergingDatasets",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody MergeRule getMergingDatasets(HttpServletRequest req, @RequestBody MergeRule parameter) throws IOException {

        System.out.println(parameter.getCompanyId());
        System.out.println(parameter.getClassId());

/*      System.out.println(req.getParameter("company"));
        System.out.println(req.getParameter("companyClass"));*/

        List<DropdownMenu> mergingDatasets = mergeRuleDAO.getMergingDataSets(parameter.getCompanyId(), parameter.getClassId());

        return (MergeRule) mergingDatasets;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your MergeRule must containers all your Ajax's params. But your controller use get, so you can't use `@RequestBody`, you need two `@RequestParam`.

 such as:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getMergingDatasets",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody MergeRule getMergingDatasets(HttpServletRequest req, @RequestParam String companyId, @RequestParam String classId) throws IOException {
    System.out.println(companyId);
    System.out.println(classId);

    /*System.out.println(req.getParameter("company"));
     System.out.println(req.getParameter("companyClass"));*/

    List<DropdownMenu> mergingDatasets = mergeRuleDAO.getMergingDataSets(companyId, classId);

    return (MergeRule) mergingDatasets;
}
```